# access the 'nth' element in a for loop with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to loop through elements with a class of `preference` and set their text property to a string based on the index of the loop. However, getting the 'nth' element with class of preference isn't working in this case, I receive the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[i].text is not a function`

What is the correct way to do this?

```
$(".email-notification-preference").load("templates/email-notification-preference.html", function (data) {
    for (i = 0; i < numPreferences; i++) {
        $('.preference')[i].text(preferences[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*$('.preference')* returns an array of DomElement and they have no method .text().

I would suggest, using

```
$('.preference')[i].innerText = preferences[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the brackets syntax. `$('.preference')` returns a jquery collection of elements but `$('.preference')[i]` returns pure DOM node object that is not wrapped in jquery. Because of that you have the method `eq` that returns the jQuery object at a specified index of the collection like so: `$('.preference').eq(i)`.

However this is not the best way to go since on each iteration you query the DOM for the `.preference` which is expensive. Better cache the result in a variable and make use of the `.each` method:

```
var items  = $('.preference');

items.each(function(i){
    $(this).text(preferences[i]); // or this.innerText = preferences[i]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change that for

```
var domPreferences = $('.preference');
for (i = 0; i < domPreferences.length; i++) {
  domPreferences[i].innerText = preferences[i];
}
```